# Is there a boot option for keyboard layout?

Tags: boot, keyboard-layout

I’ve used rescue CDs that allow the keyboard layout to be selected at boot time, by choosing from a menu or by adding `kb=uk` to the boot command line alongside `noapic` and the like.

Does Ubuntu support anything like this when booting from a live ISO, or is the keyboard layout only changeable after the system has finished booting?

Comment: It depends on how you prepared your bootable media. IIRC with raw ISO you can press some key and it lets you choose language and keyboard locale.

Answer (score 2):

I did not test this with a current 14.04 LiveCD but as an example for german layout i used this in the past:

`keyboard-configuration/layout=de` for the preseed file used by debian-installer

or simply

`setkmap=de` for the grub boot line.